# Question regarding interior and closure in a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(\mathbb{X}, \tau)$ is a Topological Space. Are the following 14 sets distinct for some $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$?
$$A$$ $$\operatorname{int}(A),$$ $$\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}(A),$$ $$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}(A),$$ $$\operatorname{cl}(A),$$ $$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A),$$ $$\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A).$$ $$(A)^c$$
$$(\operatorname{cl}(A))^c,$$
$$(\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A))^c,$$
$$(\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A))^c,$$
$$(\operatorname{int}(A))^c,$$
$$(\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}(A))^c,$$
$$(\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}(A))^c.$$

Comment: See [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_Closure-Complement_Problem) for an intuitive visual representation.

Comment: Thanks! The notation is a little different but I think they are the same sets.